# read formatted values from stdin using sscanf

Tags: c, scanf, stdin

I am writing a code to read inputs from the keyboard (stdin) and print them.
The standard inputs are like the following.

```
(6, 10) (6, 12) (6, 20) (6, 25) (9, 25) (10,25)
```

So the values are in pairs between brackets. There might be none or multiple spaces between the values. e.g.

```
  ( 6 , 10 )    ( 6, 12 ) (6, 20) (6, 25) (9, 25) (10,25    )
```

My code needs to be able to jump the spaces and brackets between values, and terminates reading values when there is a new line.

My attempt was as below:

```
void main()
{
    int key, value;

    char input[1000]; //assume the input is than 1000 bits and initiate the inputs as strings
    char *pointer;

    printf("enter key-value pairs of integer numbers like (a,b)(c,d): ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    pointer = input;

    //read the pairs of values one at a time until the last pair
    //                       leave space before and after value and brackets to skip spaces
    while (sscanf(pointer, " ( %d , %d ) ", &key, &value) == 2) 
    {
        printf("key is %d, value is %d", key, value);
    }
}
```

However, the code enters in an infinite loop of printing 6 and 10. Could someone give me some hints on how to fix it? Much appreciated

Comment: Consider this: What is the value of `pointer` after each call to `sscanf`?

Comment: The `pointer` must be still pointed at the start of `input[]` hence why it enters in the infinite loop. However, I have written something similar with fscanf and it works when reading from a text file. e.g. while (fscanf(fp, "( %d , %d ) ", &key, &value) == 2)  {printf....}

Comment: Are there always 6 pairs per line?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, the number of user inputs are unknown

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the code by updating the pointer value in the sscanf() loop, thanks to the hint given by @Ture Pålsson.

```
void main()
{
    int key, value;

    char input[1000]; //assume the input is than 1000 bits and initiate the inputs as strings
    char *pointer;
    int offset;

    printf("enter key-value pairs of integer numbers like (a,b)(c,d): ");
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    pointer = input;

    //read the pairs of values one at a time until the last pair
    //                       leave space before and after value and brackets to skip spaces
    while (sscanf(pointer, " ( %d , %d ) %n", &key, &value, &offset) == 2) 
    {
        printf("key is %d, value is %d", key, value);
        pointer = pointer + offset
    }
}
```